# How do I type some letters with an overbar?

Tags: linux, ssh, special-characters

How can I type characters with an overbar, like the `NOT` symbol in math, when in a linux SSH shell with no GUI?

Comment: It would help if you specificed your OS, and maybe posted a link to a picture of what you want exactly.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to type them? In Microsoft Word? In an email?

Comment: I'm under linux terminal(ssh shell), no GUI available.

Comment: Linux terminal is not synonymous with ssh shell. In fact, you can ssh from windows, in which case you will be in a linux shell over ssh from a windows terminal and a windows ssh client. And it is the terminal part that matters here. Which terminal program are you using? On which system?

Answer (score 3):

Under Windows, you can use character map to locate and copy the character you want.  In Character Map, check the Advanced View box and search for "Macron" to get a list of all characters with the bar.

To open the character map:

- Windows XP and earlier: Start > Run, type in `charmap` then hit <kbd>enter</kbd>
- Windows Vista/7: Start, type in `character map`

Comment: You mean one can only select it one by one under windows?

Comment: Actually, character map allows the selection of multiple characters, but individual characters must be re-copied for different combinations.

Comment: @berk : The user asked explicitly about Linux, not Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Press:

```
Ctrl+Shif+u
```

Then type `0304` and press Enter. Now type the letter you want. `0304` is [Unicode combining code](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0304/index.htm) for that character.

Comment: Note that this is for Linux.

Comment: It works in my system: Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit using bash.

Comment: Doesn't work in SSH shell.

Comment: Well, you need UTF-8 support. What is the output of `locale`? If it doesn't show LANG=XXXXXX.utf8 then you can't use utf-8 characters

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-U is specific to GTK-based programs (such as GNOME Terminal). It won't work in, for example, PuTTY.

Answer (score 1):

In which program? Look in the font settings in whichever program for something like "Overline" or "Overstrike." Not all programs support such font decorations.

If the program you're using supports Unicode entities then you can probably use the [Overline Combine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline) character entity to accomplish this. For example, in H̅T̅M̅L̅.